# How to configure Symfony 4 with Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm trying to deploy an [application based on Symfony 4](https://github.com/kevinpapst/kimai2) on a server. The server runs other applications and for separating them I am using Nginx's `proxy_pass`, then for example I would configure:

```
location /application {
  proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:85/;
}
```

The application runs but when Symfony generates paths for assets or redirects, these are all relative to `/` instead of `/application/` as it doesn't know what the real path is. I've searched the documentation but I haven't found the way to inform this version of Symfony the real path (I'm assuming this sould be done application-level that it can't be solved on Nginx). Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Set in config/package/framework.yaml (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#base-path)

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_path: "/application"
```

I think you must set in your nginx.conf

```
location /application {
      rewrite ^/application(.*)$ /application$1 break;
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:85/;
}
```